# Browser Preview Utility

Tags: debugging

Are there any programs that render websites from the point of view of different browsers?  In other words, I'd like to be able to open and view websites as if it were Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

It would be a bonus if the utility has a paned interface that lets you view pages side by side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also can use adobe's https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html

BrowserLab provides web designers exact renderings of their web pages in multiple browsers and operating systems, on demand. BrowserLab is a powerful solution for cross-browser compatibility testing, featuring multiple viewing and comparison tools, as well as customizable preferences.

**updated,**

you can also [litmusapp](http://litmusapp.com/), another excellent utility, allowing you to test a website in different browsers but also emails.

Answer (score 0):

http://browsershots.org/